# How to configure proxychains properly?

Tags: kali-linux, proxy, proxychains

I'm using Kali 2020.4. Proxychains worked for me on 2020.2 version but not from 2020.3 onwards. On terminal when i use `proxychains firefox`  it is getting terminated instantly by showing this.

```
┌──(sohan㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ proxychains firefox www.google.com
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(sohan㉿kali)-[~]
└─$
```

I did the same steps in Parrot OS, and its working. Here in Kali I couldn't find what's going wrong. Here is my proxychains.conf file.

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#       http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use different versions of socks4 and socks5 on the same port. So delete one of the lines at the very bottom of the `proxychains.conf` config.

Also check if tor is running on port 9050: `systemctl status tor`

You can follow this [guide](https://fazlearefin.blogspot.com/2020/07/tunneling-traffic-over-tor-network.html)

Comment: I tried as you said but still getting the same issue. But i noticed that when i used 'proxychains curl https://ipinfo.io/city' i was getting different location means its working, but when i tried 'proxychains firefox' and check location inside browser, it's showing mine.

Comment: Can you check what kind of *Network Settings* you are using inside firefox? Try choosing No Proxy in the firefox Network Settings

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and the problem was I tried execute the command when the other example of firefox was opened in the other window. In the other words, be sure that firefox is closed when "proxychains firefox" is executing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but resolved it by using a non root user account. Create another user, log into that user account and run the command again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I realized that I had firefox open, after closing it there was no problem